# ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined on stripe.fileUploads.create

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, typescript-typings

When i try to use stripe.fileUploads.create i get that create is undefined?

ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

i followed the request format in the docs using the stripe/typings library in node.js https://stripe.com/docs/api/files/create

```
/**
 * "@types/stripe": "^6.31.23"
 * "stripe": "^7.8.0" */

import * as Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('mykey');

function uploadFileToStripe(fileUrl:string,fileType:string,fileName:string):Promise<Stripe.fileUploads.IFileUpdate>{
    const upload: Promise<Stripe.fileUploads.IFileUpdate> = 
    stripe.fileUploads.create(
        {
            file: {
                data: fileUrl,
                name: fileName,
                type: 'image/jpeg',
            },
            purpose: 'identity_document',
        }
    );
    return upload.then(
        (document: Stripe.fileUploads.IFileUpdate) => {
            console.log('Document upload ', document);
            return document;
        }   
    ).catch(
        (_error: any) => {
            console.log('Error uploading document ', _error);
            return _error;
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are initialising the library correctly.

As stated in Stripe's documentation, no class constructor ("new") is necessary:

```
const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc")
```

Please try to import the library as follows:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe'
const stripe = Stripe('mykey')
```

**EDIT:**

Please import the library as follows:

```
import { Stripe } from 'stripe';
const stripe = Stripe('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc')
```

I've just tested the code locally and it works.

To use the `create` method you have to access the `files` key as `filesUpload` does not exist:

```
stripe.files.create(...)
```

Comment: its required as this is typescript